# AVS mismatch when billing and shipping addresses are different

Tags: checkout, authorize.net

My client is having issues with customers that input a different address for both billing and shipping during checkout using a credit card. It seems that authorize.net is trying to validate both addresses as the billing address. I ran a test order and the stack trace is below. Anyone have any ideas or encounter this before?

Thanks!!

```
2013-04-04T20:53:37+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Gateway error: The transaction has been declined because of an AVS mismatch. The address provided does not match billing address of cardholder.' in /home/ab71714/public_html/app/Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php(579): Mage::throwException('Gateway error: ...')
#1 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php(357): Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet->_place(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), '74.23', 'AUTH_CAPTURE')
#2 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(282): Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet->capture(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), '74.23')
#3 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php(385): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->capture(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice))
#4 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(439): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice->capture()
#5 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(247): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->_invoice()
#6 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(189): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->capture(NULL)
#7 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(877): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->place()
#8 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1095): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_placePayment()
#9 [internal function]: Mage_Sales_Model_Order->place()
#10 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(105): call_user_func(Array)
#11 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(159): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->_runCallbacks()
#12 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(189): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
#13 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#14 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(774): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#15 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(511): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#16 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
#17 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#18 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home/ab71714/public_html/index.php(90): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
2013-04-04T20:53:59+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Gateway error: A duplicate transaction has been submitted.' in /home/ab71714/public_html/app/Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php(579): Mage::throwException('Gateway error: ...')
#1 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php(357): Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet->_place(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), '74.23', 'AUTH_CAPTURE')
#2 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(282): Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet->capture(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), '74.23')
#3 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php(385): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->capture(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice))
#4 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(439): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice->capture()
#5 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(247): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->_invoice()
#6 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(189): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->capture(NULL)
#7 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(877): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->place()
#8 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1095): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_placePayment()
#9 [internal function]: Mage_Sales_Model_Order->place()
#10 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(105): call_user_func(Array)
#11 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(159): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->_runCallbacks()
#12 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(189): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
#13 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#14 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(774): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#15 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(511): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#16 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
#17 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#18 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home/ab71714/public_html/index.php(90): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
2013-04-04T20:55:36+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Gateway error: A duplicate transaction has been submitted.' in /home/ab71714/public_html/app/Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php(579): Mage::throwException('Gateway error: ...')
#1 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php(357): Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet->_place(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), '74.23', 'AUTH_CAPTURE')
#2 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(282): Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet->capture(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), '74.23')
#3 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php(385): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->capture(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice))
#4 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(439): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice->capture()
#5 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(247): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->_invoice()
#6 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(189): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->capture(NULL)
#7 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(877): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->place()
#8 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1095): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_placePayment()
#9 [internal function]: Mage_Sales_Model_Order->place()
#10 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(105): call_user_func(Array)
#11 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(159): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->_runCallbacks()
#12 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(189): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
#13 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#14 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(774): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#15 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(511): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#16 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
#17 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#18 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home/ab71714/public_html/index.php(90): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
2013-04-04T21:20:22+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Gateway error: The transaction has been declined because of an AVS mismatch. The address provided does not match billing address of cardholder.' in /home/ab71714/public_html/app/Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php(579): Mage::throwException('Gateway error: ...')
#1 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php(357): Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet->_place(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), '8.91', 'AUTH_CAPTURE')
#2 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(282): Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet->capture(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), '8.91')
#3 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php(385): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->capture(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice))
#4 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(439): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice->capture()
#5 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(247): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->_invoice()
#6 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(189): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->capture(NULL)
#7 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(877): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->place()
#8 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1095): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_placePayment()
#9 [internal function]: Mage_Sales_Model_Order->place()
#10 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(105): call_user_func(Array)
#11 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(159): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->_runCallbacks()
#12 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(189): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
#13 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#14 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(774): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#15 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(511): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#16 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
#17 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#18 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /home/ab71714/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home/ab71714/public_html/index.php(90): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
```

Edit 4/9/13:
I have the following settings in authorize.net but am still having the issue!

[image: AVSsettings]

Comment: Do you have a custom module overriding the Checkout or Customer modules? It might be saving the wrong address as billing

Comment: What version of Magento?

Comment: I'm on version 1.7. I have Firegento installed and for the rewrites it says next to "Webshopapps_Ordermanager_Block_Sales_Order_Grid" - not okay. I'm thinking this could be a culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a setting for the client to set in their authorize.net account if they are okay with shipping to non-billing addresses:

- http://www.authorize.net/content/dam/authorize/documents/merchant_guide.pdf

**Refer Chapter 3 (Integration Settings)**

Comment: Thank you! I will be trying that soon and will mark as correct if it works!

Comment: Hey, I don't get these settings. I have posted a screenshot above of what the current settings are. Do they look wrong to you?

Comment: Hey nevermind. I actually disabled google checkout and paypal (which we aren't using) and for some reason it works now..